# How to implement vuex persistence for nuxt.js?

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, vuex, persistence

Nuxt version: 2.15.8

I am not initializing vuex the traditional way with `Vue.use(Vuex)` and `new Vuex.Store`.

Instead I am doing the nuxt.js way, https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/cookbook/store/#basic-typing.

I don't know how to add plugins for state persistence in this case.

Comment: SO is not a how-to platform. What did you tried so far and what is not working?

Comment: Also, you don't have to do anything special here, besides creating a `store/index.ts` file. The typing is local. Nuxt will detect that you do have a file in `store` and enable Vuex for you.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with vuex-persist:
https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-persist#tips-for-nuxt

```js
// Inside - nuxt.config.js
export default {
   plugins: [{ src: '~/plugins/vuex-persist.js', mode: 'client' }],
}
```

```js
// ~/plugins/vuex-persist.js
import VuexPersistence from 'vuex-persist'

export default ({ store }) => {
  new VuexPersistence({
  /* your options */
  }).plugin(store);
}
```